# Simultaneous equations how can I do it

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $$k-5=w \\ t=x \\  \dfrac{k\cdot w}{t+x}=57$$ And the question is asking for $k$.

I don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
t&=x\\
\frac{kw}{t+x}&=57\\
\therefore \frac{kw}{2t}&=57\\
\therefore kw&=57\cdot2t\\
k-5&=w\\
\times\mbox{ k},\\
k^2-5k&=kw\\
k^2-5k&=114t\\
k^2-5k-114t&=0\\
k &=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{25+456t}}{2}
\end{align}